# GNU Makefile wildcard for directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have several directories which may have subdirectories, and I'm going to compress each one to a file if any file in that directory is changed.

For example, I have 2 directories dir1 dir2, and I want to compress them to comp_dir1.tar.gz and comp_dir2.tar.gz.

I wrote the following code:

```
comp_%.tar.gz : %/$(shell find % -name "*")
    tar -czvf $@ $<
```

But I got the error:

```
find: ‘%’: No such file or directory
```

It is obvious that I can't use "%" in the shell command.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make tarballs of any of those several directories in which any file at any depth has changed, or you want to make a tarball of any directory at any depth in which a file has changed?

Comment: The former one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need in any case is a list of the directories you want to compress. Using that, you can use a GNU Make feature [*Remaking Makefiles*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html) to generate "dependency files" which include all files found in these directories. Here is a working example:

```
DIRECTORIES:=dir1 dir2
ARCHIVES:=$(addsuffix .tar.gz,$(addprefix comp_,$(DIRECTORIES)))

all: $(ARCHIVES)

comp_%.tar.gz.d: %
    echo $(@:.d=) $(@): $(shell find $< -name "*") > $(@)

# include the dependency files, this will cause GNU make to attempt creating
# them using the above pattern rule.
-include $(addsuffix .d,$(ARCHIVES))

comp_%.tar.gz: %
    tar czvf $@ $<

.PHONY: all
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a good idea to generate the dependency files first.